# react useState initialize value again

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

i am facing a weired issue.i am using redux and react . react useState initialize my data again when it gets new props from store.the docs says that useState initial value only in first render but i cannot understand why this is happening

```
function UploadFileInfo({
createdCategory
}){
const [data, setData] = useState({
    video_id: null,
    title: 'title',
    category_id: '2',
    channel_category_id: '',
    info: '',
    tags: [],
    playlists: '',
    enable_comments: 0,
    enable_watermark: false,
    banner_id: null,
  });
return (
    <Paper square className={classes.paper}>
    </Paper>
  );
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  tags: makeSelectTags(),
  categories: makeSelectCategories(),
  createdTag: makeSelectCreateTag(),
  createdCategory: makeSelectCreateCategory(),
  createdPlaylist: makeSelectCreatedPlaylist(),
  myCategories: makeSelectMyCategories(),
  myPlaylists: makeSelectMyPlaylists(),
  uploadedFile: makeSelectUploadFile(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
    addTag: title => dispatch(createTag(title)),
    addCategory: title => dispatch(createCategory(title)),
    addPlaylist: title => dispatch(createPlaylist(title)),
    publishVideo: data => dispatch(createVideo(data)),
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default compose(withConnect)(UploadFileInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect`. It is simillar to `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` react lifecycles. You can tell react to re-render the page when if certain values get change.You can defined those values inside the [] in `useEffect` function

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setData({
       //set data in here 
    })
  
  },[addTag,addCategory, //values that get changed])
```

Comment: still doesn't work.useState initialize data with default value when my component gets new props from store.that's my problem

Comment: How are you using this component ? Can you share the code sample of it ?

Comment: i upload component and its parent.https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-visvesvaraya-guetk?file=/src/uploadPage.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5974845/amila-dulanjana https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-visvesvaraya-guetk?file=/src/uploadPage.js

Comment: I checked, but i didnt able to find any issues. are you sure that `setValue` function works   correctly ?

Comment: yeah.setValue works correctly.this works perfectly before.i am start thinking this is from ide or something.i thing i have to restart my pc :|

Comment: the problem was from parent component.action causes parent component to re render .do you know how can i connect my parent to store and stop it from rendering again when child gets new prop from store? https://stackoverflow.com/users/5974845/amila-dulanjana