# React setState hook keeps resetting and rendering the page twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-state

I have an react app `Form` component split into `Login` and `Signup` forms. It is supposed to render the `Signup` by default but switch to `Login` if login is button is clicked. When `login` button is clicked, the page switches to the `Login` form very briefly before switching back to the `Signup` form. I don't know what is causing this. I have tried placing `const [page, setPage] = setState("signup")` in the parent `App` and passing `setPage` as a prop along with `page`. This produced the same results. I believe this issue is similar to  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541358/react-usestate-initialize-value-again) but that was not resolved.
Here is the app:

```js
import Form from "./components/Signup-Form.js";
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <Form />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and `Signup-Form.js`:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Forms.css";
import { InputField, Buttons } from "./Inputs";
function Form() {
    const [page, setPage] = useState("signup");
    const pageLabel = page;

    let Signup = () => {
        function toLogin() {
            setPage("login");
        }
        return (
            <form action="" method="get" className="form">
                <div className="input-container">
                    <InputField name="Company Name" id="comp-name" type="text" />
                    <InputField name="Company ID" id="comp-id" type="text" />
                    <InputField name="Username" id="username" type="text" />
                    <InputField name="Email" id="email" type="email" />
                    <InputField name="Password" id="password" type="password" />
                    <InputField name="Confirm Password" id="confirm-password" type="password" />
                </div>
                <div className="btns">
                    <Buttons name="Sign Up" id="signup-btn" type="submit" cls="success" />
                    <Buttons name="Log In" id="login-btn" type="button" cls="success" alt="true" onClick={toLogin} />
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    };
    let Login = () => {
        function toSignup() {
            setPage("signup");
        }
        return (
            <form action="" method="get" className="form">
                <div className="input-container">
                    <InputField name="Company ID" id="comp-id" type="text" />
                    <InputField name="Password" id="password" type="password" />
                </div>
                <div className="btns">
                    <Buttons name="Log In" id="login-btn" type="submit" cls="success" />
                    <Buttons name="Sign Up" id="signup-btn" type="submit" cls="success" alt onClick={toSignup} />
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    };
    let form = (formType) => (
        <div className="outer-wrapper">
            <div className="form-wrapper">
                <label className="form-title">{pageLabel}</label>
                {formType}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    if (page === "signup") {
        const signup = Signup();
        return form(signup);
    } else if (page === "login") {
        const login = Login();
        return form(login);
    }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why after you click on Login button and get Login page and the page immediately re-renders and you get the Signup page is conditional render in your example. Right after clicking on Login button your state still previous and for this reason after click you get the main (Signup) page.

Suggest to change the structure render into smth like this:

```
...
return (
  <div className="outer-wrapper">
    <div className="form-wrapper">
      <label className="form-title">{pageLabel}</label>
      {page === "signup" && Signup()}
      {page === "login" && Login()}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Here is the example in an action - https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-water-6jj18?file=/src/App.js